# Show that this simple functional is not bounded below

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Define  $\varphi(u) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \displaystyle\frac{{|u'| }^2}{2} - \displaystyle\frac{{u }^2}{4} - hu \ dt$, $u \in H^{1}_{0}(0,1)$ where $h: [0,1] \rightarrow R$ is a continuous functions. Show that $\varphi$ is not bounded below.

I tried to use basic inequalities like the AM - GM , Cauchy Schawrz and the imersion $H^{1}_{0}(0,1) \subset L^4(0,1)$. But these thing not worked. Someone can give me a hintto prove  the affirmation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your definition of $\phi(u)$, is it $\vert u \vert'^2$ or $\vert u' \vert^2$ under the integral sign?

Comment: it is the second option. i did a error. sorry for my error. i corrected the error. thanks for your comentary about the definition of $\varphi$

Comment: Hey!  Not Problem!  Glad to help out!  Glad we got it right!

Comment: An idea would be to test the eigenfunctions of the Laplace operator, ie $u=\sin(n\pi x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false; the functional is bounded from below. Begin with $h\equiv 0$ for simplicity:   the functional
$$ \varphi(u) = \int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{(u')^2}{2} - \displaystyle\frac{{u }^2}{4}\right)\,dt  $$
is never negative. Indeed, the 2nd form of [Wirtinger's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions#Second_version) says that 
$$\int_0^1 u^2 \le \frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^1 (u')^2$$
hence
$$ \varphi(u) \ge \left( \frac12 - \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\right) \int_0^{1} \frac{(u')^2}{2} \tag{1}$$

With general $h$, we can bound the term with $hu$ by $-\|h\|_2\|u\|_2 $, which, being linear in $u$, is still dominated by the right side of (1).

Comment: thanks . You're right . My book is wrong. thanks for your answer =)